# Delete Access form from Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have 2 forms in an Access database (Access 2007-10) that are feeding records into 2 independent tables. I am trying to delete these forms using VBA in an Excel workbook. 
My Access database has NO database password but the VBA project in Access HAS a password. In the Access database I have created a sub procedure (named DeleteAll) which contains the following code for each form:

```
Docmd.DeleteObject acform, "Name of form"
```

When I call this code from my Excel VBA, the Access database gives me an error:

> Run-time error '2017': Microsoft helps protect this Visual Basic for
>   Applications Project with a password. You must supply the password in
>   the Visual Basic Editor before you can perform this operation.

Funny thing is if I were to delete a query using this method, it gets deleted easily. I am experiencing this problem with forms only.

Answer (score 0):

Ms Access query does not have a module attached. All forms with VBA module attaches act as a Class. To delete/Edit VBA Module/class you need to supply the password.

Comment: I see. And is there a way I can send the password from excel to access when I run the access macro?